# looping Nested If else in a TreeMap logic

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, treemap

I'm putting values in a `TreeMap` as follows:

```
  if (hdr.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Ip4")) {
     map.put(1, f);
 } else if (hdr.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ethernet")) {
     map.put(2, f);
 } else if (hdr.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tcp")) {
     map.put(3, f);
 } else
 if (hdr.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("udp")) {
     map.put(4, f);
 }
```

And I'm trying to retrieve it using:

```
Iterator < Map.Entry < Integer, Field >> entries = map2.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry < Integer, Field > entry = entries.next();

    if ((entry.getKey() == 1)) {

    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getSource());
    stringBuilder.append(",");
    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getDestination());
    } else if ((entry.getKey() == 2)) {

    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getSource());
    stringBuilder.append(",");
    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getDestination());
    } else if ((entry.getKey() == 3)) {

    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getSource());
    stringBuilder.append(",");
    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getDestination());
    } else if ((entry.getKey() == 4)) {

    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getSource());
    stringBuilder.append(",");
    stringBuilder.append(entry.getValue().getDestination());
    }

}
```

Now, the output I want is if any key is not found, it should go in an else part (which I have not included here as I am not getting the desired output) and it should append

```
               stringBuilder.append(,,);
```

for example

```
        If key 1 contains 12,13
        If key 2 is not present ,,
        If key 3 contains 10,11
        If key 4 contains 14,15
```

So the desired outout should be

```
       12,13,,10,11,14,15
```

Kindly help me with logic as I am breaking my head over this.

Thanks

Comment: you are iterating over the entries that exist in that map, so if 2 is not in the map, nothing will be printed for it.

Comment: Can't you just have some variable that loops from 1 to 4, then uses `get` to see what's in the map?

Comment: @Eran , If 2 is not present I want (,,) to be printed, also its that at anytime either 1 , 2 ,3 , 4 or any combination of it will not be present , So I have to check if any key is present or not for the values.

Comment: David , I will check that and will update

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint David , I solved it using

```
    for (int i=1 ; i<=map2.size()+1; i++){
        if(map2.containsKey(i))
        {
            //appendString(map2.get(i));    

            stringBuilder.append(map2.get(i).getSource());
            stringBuilder.append(",");
            stringBuilder.append(map2.get(i).getDestination());

        }
        else{
            stringBuilder.append(",,");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you test the case where 3 and 4 are present, but 1 and 2 are not.  You might not get the result you expect.